# What is heartbeat in celery?

Tags: celery

I can't work out what heartbeat is for in celery. Someone writes that this is how the worker checks the viability of the broker, but then why do I get messages that some node has left the party? Why do I need heartbeat if, when I lose connection with the node, the task that it performs will not immediately return to the queue? Please give a good explanation in your own words "What is heartbeat and what is it used for"

Comment: Each node in the cluster sends heartbeat - it is basically a tiny message the worker boardcasts saying "hey guys, i am alive". I do not remember how frequently it is sent, but I would assume every N seconds.

Comment: @DejanLekic Yes, I also saw this, but I wonder why it is needed if, as I noticed, when the connection with the node is lost, the task that it was performing will not immediately return to the queue

Comment: By default it is 2 secs (default heartbeat inverval value). As to why it is needed... Well, think about it - how else would other nodes know that particular node is "alive" or not? Remember - they are not directly connected to each other. They are connected to the broker, and responsibility of broker is to relay messages between nodes.